# Encapsulate annotation default value by composing RequestParam annotation in spring

Tags: java, spring

If I have a mapping in a controller in spring like:

```
@RequestMapping(params = "foo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String findAllBars(@RequestParam(value = "amount", defaultValue = "10") int amount, Model uiModel) {
```

Can I make an annotation and have the default value of 10 above encapsulated? Like:

```
@RequestMapping(params = "foo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String findAllBars(@MyAmountAnnotation int amount, Model uiModel) {
```

And have spring understand my annotation as expected. I found https://stackabuse.com/spring-annotations-requestmapping-and-its-variants/ and got a bit hopeful when I saw what they did with their @GetMapping, @PostMapping, et.c.

However I got compilation error 'RequestParam not applicable to annotation type' when I tried:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@RequestParam(value = "amount", defaultValue = "10")
public @interface MyAmountAnnotation {
    //...
```

Can I do it like this to 'encapsulate' a verbose annotation to a specialised one? What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can create your MyAmountAnnotation annotation like follow :

```
  @Target({ElementType.PARAMETER})
  @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
  @Documented
  public @interface MyAmountAnnotation  {
    @AliasFor("name")
    String value() default "amount";

    @AliasFor("value")
    String name() default "amount";

    boolean required() default true;

    String defaultValue() default "10";
  }
```

And use it this way :

```
@RequestMapping(params = "foo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String findAllBars(@MyAmountAnnotation int amount, Model uiModel) {..
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure it is correct, have you tried it? I'm getting 'Optional int parameter 'amount' is present but cannot be translated into a null value due to being declared as a primitive type. Consider declaring it as object wrapper for the corresponding primitive type.' I've tried with boolean required() default as true and false.

Comment: @Adam Try defining the amount parameter on the function  like `@MyAmountAnnotation Integer amount` instead of `@MyAmountAnnotation int amount`

Comment: No that doesn't work either, I don't have insight into the reflection magic that happens under the hood of Spring. But it feels like the 'RequestParam' annotation cannot just be swapped out without being part of it, compose-style like in the linked blog.

Comment: @Adam I have tested it, it seems working fine for me

Comment: @Adam what error you get after changing `int` to `Integer`?

Comment: It compiles for me, but I get null instead of the default value. Are you saying you sucessfully call the mapping with no request params and the default value is injected via the annotation?

Comment: Hey Adam! Author of the article here :)
I don't know if this question is still relevant or not - but I'll add the topic of creating custom annotations with default values to our topic pool and hopefully publish an article on it soon. Thank you for reading!